# exp:channel:form and relationships

Tags: relationships, forms

So, running on 2.5.5 I would do the following (with SafeCracker instead):

```
{exp:channel:form channel="resumeer" return="folketinget/resume_ret/ENTRY_ID" include_jquery="no"}
    <p>Overskrift: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100"  /></p>
     <input type="hidden" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75" size="50" />
     <input type="hidden" name="allow_comments" value="y" />
     <input type="hidden" name="relation_lovforslag" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="status" value="Closed" />
     {field:wygwam_basic}
     <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="GEM KLADDE" class="form-submit" /></p>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

This is for creating a related entry to the main channel entry. The field relation_lovforslag is for that purpose and it just sends the entry_id of the main entry. However, this doesn’t work anymore and I wonder what the proper syntax is for 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work with:

`<input type="hidden" name="relation_lovforslag[data][]" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>" />`

Answer (score 1):

To output the information this worked for me:

```
<p class="grid-row"><em>Fav Style:</em><span>{options:member_favourite_drinks}{if selected}{option_name},{/if}{/options:member_favourite_drinks}</span></p>
```

... and to have this in a select list:

```
{custom_fields}
     {if field_name=="member_favourite_drinks"}
            <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[data][]" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="">Select...</option>
                  {options}
                      <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
                  {/options}
             </select>
     {/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

Comment: Yes. But I want to hardcode the choice - I want the relation to be he entry_id.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<input type="hidden" id="relation_lovforslag" name="relation_lovforslag[][data][]" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>" />
```

Comment: I haven't tried that exact variant - I got it working eventually with: `<input type="hidden" name="relation_lovforslag[data][]" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>" />`